# how to get document's title with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to use CSS3 selector "content" to add some text to some HTML, e.g the document's title, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't implement it in pure CSS. Content Property values can only be one of the following:

```
content: normal                                /* Keywords that cannot be combined with other values */ content: none
content: 'prefix'                              /* &lt;string&gt; value, non-latin characters must be encoded e.g. \00A0 for &nbsp; */
content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html) /* &lt;uri&gt; value */
content: chapter_counter                       /* &lt;counter&gt; values */
content: attr(value string)                    /* attr() value linked to the HTML attribute value */ 
content: open-quote                            /* Language- and position-dependant keywords */ content: close-quote
content: no-open-quote content: no-close-quote
content: open-quote chapter_counter            /* Except for normal and none, several values can be used simultaneously */
content: inherit
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content for more detail.

Using `attr` can only grab attrubites of the current element.

But you can add `data` attributes like this:

```
<style>
.article-title:before{
    content:attr(data-mytag);font-size:0.5em;margin-right:1em}
</style>
<span data-mytag="Tips here" class="article-title">1</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll use JS to resolve my problem because I wanted to add some styles for websites which are not mine.

Comment: If you wan to add extra styles for links that refers to other website, you can try `a[href^="http://"]:before{content:url('any-icon-you-like.png')}`